# Configure schema user in Oracle R2dbc

Tags: oracle, r2dbc

I have two users DBOWNER & DBUSER.
DBOWNER will have right to all DDL commands and will create the tables in it.
DBUSER has CURD rights on DBOWNER tables.

From Oracle R2DBC I want to use DBUSER to perform data entry in tables inside DBOWNER.

Comment: What's your question, then?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.